# Can't update text of UITextView in a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I've been running into an issue that seems to keep coming up on the web, but have been unable to resolve the issue... I'm trying to set the text of a UITextView that's inside of a custom UITableViewCell in a load function that's called on the cell when it's contents are being rendered in its table view.

[image]

These are my current settings on my textview that's inside my custom tableviewcell. Note that UserInteraction is NOT enabled, but Editable and Selectable ARE.

[image]

This is the controller for my custom UITableViewCell, which contains the function 'loadCell'

[image]

This is the cellForRowAtIndexPath that puts the custom tableViewCell into the tableView, and it calls the loadCell() function when it's initialized.

[image]

This is the result, with the textView obviously not being updated correctly.

Another note I'd like to add is that if I update the textView during the awakeFromNib function in the custom UITableViewCell controller, it successfully is able to change the text in the textField.

If anyone can help me out, that would be super duper awesome, as I'd love to be able to use textViews instead of labels :) Thanks!

Comment: You only call loadCell for your first row. There is no point in your if statement. Just call loadCell for every row.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @stefos — you likely need to review what you're doing in the table:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. Also make sure your reusable cell identifier matches what you registered the cell class with either in code or in InterfaceBuilder.

Comment: I'm going to implement more clauses, I just haven't yet in this example. Thank you, though! I'm going to be loading different custom cells at different indices on this tableView.

Comment: @Erator I'm sure they're linked up correctly, as it wouldn't be loading the cell otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out that the problem was in the cellForRowAtIndexPath function, in which I was attempting to dequeueReusableCell twice (once at the functions start, and once if the index was 0). I'm not entirely sure why this is causing a problem, though I can make an assumption that it was attempting to dequeue the same cell twice, and was causing problems.

Either way, getting rid of
`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MenuItemDescriptionCell")`
did the trick.

Hope this helps someone in the future! Happy coding :)